# Webpage that lets user draw a picture - on iPhone

Tags: iphone, html, mobile-safari

I am making a webpage for iDevices and need to allow the user to draw pictures. There would be a box and they would scribble in whatever they need. Don't need color or fancy brushes. When they are done, I would need some way of collecting that input and getting it back to the server, vector or bitmap format would be fine.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a premium Tutorial on Net TutsPlus. It covers CSS3, HTML5 and the canvas element. The Canvas element is supported by Mobile Safari.

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/how-to-create-a-web-based-drawing-application-using-canvas-new-premium-tutorial/

Comment: Thanks, I used the ninilogic link along with the free example at http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1867-Drawing-On-The-iPhone-Canvas-With-jQuery-And-ColdFusion.htm and got it working.